# Eclipse plugin for adding custom library

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a Custom ClassPath entry as mention [here](http://denizstij.blogspot.in/2009/07/customized-classpath-contributor.html). I have done as mentioned in the link and also referred the source code of JUnit and M2E doing this. But when I select the new Custom Library and clicks next, I am getting the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI can not access a member of class com.company.eclipse.buildpath.CustomClasspathContainerPage with modifiers "protected"
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.util.CoreUtility$1.run(CoreUtility.java:101)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.util.CoreUtility.createExtension(CoreUtility.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.ClasspathContainerDescriptor.createPage(ClasspathContainerDescriptor.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.ClasspathContainerWizard.getContainerPage(ClasspathContainerWizard.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.ClasspathContainerWizard.getNextPage(ClasspathContainerWizard.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage.getNextPage(WizardPage.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:878)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.ClasspathContainerWizard.openWizard(ClasspathContainerWizard.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.BuildPathDialogAccess.chooseContainerEntries(BuildPathDialogAccess.java:334)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.openContainerSelectionDialog(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:892)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.libaryPageCustomButtonPressed(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:266)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.access$0(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage$LibrariesAdapter.customButtonPressed(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.buttonPressed(TreeListDialogField.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.doButtonSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:400)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.access$2(TreeListDialogField.java:396)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField$2.widgetSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:361)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Below are the contents of CustomClasspathContainerPage

```
public class CustomClasspathContainerPage extends NewElementWizardPage implements IClasspathContainerPage, IClasspathContainerPageExtension {

    private IClasspathEntry containerEntry;

    IJavaProject javaProject;

    protected CustomClasspathContainerPage() {
        super("CustomContainerPage");
        setTitle("Add custom library");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(IJavaProject javaProject, IClasspathEntry[] currentEntries) {
        this.javaProject = javaProject;
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        container.setLayout((Layout) layout);
        new Label(container, 0).setText("This will set the Custom library to this project.");
        this.setControl((Control) container);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean finish() {
        if (containerEntry == null) {
            containerEntry = JavaCore.newContainerEntry(Core.CONTAINER_PATH);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public IClasspathEntry getSelection() {
        return containerEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(IClasspathEntry containerEntry) {
        this.containerEntry = containerEntry;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is declared to be `protected` it must be `public`:

```
public CustomClasspathContainerPage() {
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helped. I overlooked things.